# what's wrong with the Gyroscope in unity3d(tested on google nexus 7)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gyroscope

I write a script in c# to test the Gyroscope in unity3d 4.0.
and get the information blow:
[image]

However I rotate or move my google nexus 7. Every parameter keeps "0" ; I don't know why.

anyone  can help me ?

here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class gyroscope : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Gyroscope gyo1;
    private bool gyoBool;
    //private Quaternion rotFix;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        gyoBool = SystemInfo.supportsGyroscope;
        Debug.Log (gyoBool.ToString ());
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
    gyo1=Input.gyro;

    }

    void OnGUI ()
    {
        if (gyoBool != null) 
        {
            GUI.Label (new Rect (10, Screen.height / 2 - 50, 100, 100), gyoBool.ToString ());
            if (gyoBool == true) 
            {

                GUI.Label (new Rect (10, Screen.height / 2-100, 500, 100), "gyro supported");
                GUI.Label (new Rect (10, Screen.height / 2, 500, 100), "rotation rate:" + gyo1.rotationRate.ToString ());
                GUI.Label (new Rect (10, Screen.height / 2 + 50, 500, 100), "gravity:      " + gyo1.gravity.ToString ());
                GUI.Label (new Rect (10, Screen.height / 2 + 100, 500, 100), "attitude:     " + gyo1.attitude.ToString ());
                GUI.Label (new Rect (10, Screen.height / 2 + 150, 500, 100), "type:         " + gyo1.GetType ().ToString ());
            } 
            else
                GUI.Label (new Rect (Screen.width / 2 - 100, Screen.height / 2, 100, 100), "not supported");
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Could you try changing all your `ToString()` calls for rotationRate, gravity and attitude to `ToString("F4")`? Then see if that provides some output.

Comment: I don't know the SDK but: the gyroscope is "supported;" is it "enabled?" Support doesn't necessarily imply the function is active.

Comment: it appears to be something like (0.0000,0.0000,0.0000)when performed as toString("F4");@Bart

Comment: my logic is:if( gyroscope is enabled ) then { print "supported" }

Comment: Okay, so it's not a matter of precision then. No values whatsoever. Could you try enabling it? Your current logic is if(supported). So try `Input.gyro.enbled = true;`

Comment: Not sure on the answer sorry but one thing is you shouldn't be assigning gyro in update as it means you're reassigning it every frame. You should use Awake or Start in this instance.

Comment: Also check here: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/162434/how-can-i-to-use-the-gyroscope-.html
According to that gyroscope is iOS only. Not sure if it still applies.

Comment: I tried ,but failed.@Bart

Comment: you say the point,no support on android @user2025312 ,But can you tell me how they make this possible:https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/#/content/1701

Answer (score 6):

You must enable the Gyroscope. Your Start method should look like this:

```
void Start ()
{
    gyoBool = SystemInfo.supportsGyroscope;

    if( gyoBool ) {
       gyo1=Input.gyro;
       gyo1.enabled = true;
    }

    Debug.Log (gyoBool.ToString ());
}
```

Also you don't need to assign the gyroscope to "gyo1" every frame (ie: remove gyo1=Input.gyro; from your Update method).

Comment: hey,cool man.It works ,and figures out the parameters I need, thank you so much.

Comment: I have the exact same problem and I've double checked: gyro is supported and enabled in initialization but the attitude is always zero. Any guess about the root of the problem?